# Convert variables from dataframe into nums

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert my Sex and Embarked values into num.
My solution doesn't work properly,  it changes values for all columns

```
titset[titset['Sex']=='male'] = 2
titset[titset['Sex']=='female'] = 1
titset
```

Piece of my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
data = {
'Fare': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female','male','male','female','male','female'],
'Embarked': ['S','C','Q','S','S','S','C','C','S','S']
}
titanic = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=id)
titanic
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```py
titanic["Fare"] = titanic["Fare"].map({"male": 2, "female": 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code from @Code_Different or you can use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function

```py
titanic = titanic.replace({'Fare':{'male':2,'female':1'}})
```