# How to remake this code for dataframe mapping properly

Tags: python, pandas

```
titset["Sex"] = titset["Sex"].map({"male": 2, "female": 1})
titset["Embarked"] = titset["Embarked"].map({"S": 1, "C": 2, 'Q' : 3})
```

I had such code but i was told that i can't use it because it have been already used so i'm confused how to remake it remake it to have the same functionality as it has. It changes 'male' in Sex column and 'female' values on 2 and 1, and on 'Embarked' column in replaces 'S' with 1 etc

Comment: What means "*i can't use it because it have been already used*"? Is this an assignment?

Comment: For the first one you can suggest to your teacher to use `pd.Series([set(x).difference('lame') for x in df["Sex"]], index=df.index).str.len().rsub(2)`, if they say it's too complicated come back to the `map` alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I answer your [other, very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71878043/convert-variables-from-dataframe-into-nums/71878068#71878068). If this is homework and you must do the replacement in different ways:

```py
# Assuming there are only 2 sexes
titset["Sex"] = np.where(titset["Sex"] == "female", 1, 2)

# If more than 2 sexes
titset["Sex"] = np.select(
    [
        titset["Sex"] == "female",
        titset["Sex"] == "male",
        titset["Sex"] == "other",
    ],
    [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
)

# You can also use a plain old loop
# (slow, not recommended)
new_sex = []
for sex in titset["Sex"]:
    if sex == "female":
        new_sex.append(1)
    elif sex == "male":
        new_sex.append(2)
    elif sex == "other":
        new_sex.append(3)
titset["Sex"] = new_sex
```